# Constructor parameters

Tags: c++

Player.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD_PLAYER
#define HEADER_GUARD_PLAYER

#include <string>
using std::string;


//Parent player class
class Player
{
      private:        
      protected:
         string playerName; 
         int chipCount;

      public:
         //Constructor
         Player();
         Player(string name);

}; 

//Custom Players

class PlayerSteven: public Player
{
};
class PlayerBlake: public Player
{
};
class PlayerTucker: public Player
{
};
#endif
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#define STARTCHIPS 1500

Player::Player()
{
     chipCount = STARTCHIPS;
     playerName = "Default";          
};
Player::Player(string name)
{
     playerName = name;
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Deck.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Deck deck;
    PlayerSteven steven = new PlayerSteven("Steven");
    PlayerBlake blake = new PlayerBlake("Blake");
    PlayerTucker tucker = new PlayerTucker("Tucker");

    deck.shuffle();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        deck.nextCard(x,y);
        cout << x << "," << y << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

11 C:\Users\Documents\temp\p_comp.cpp no matching function for call to `PlayerSteven::PlayerSteven(const char[7])'

11 C:\Users\Documents\temp\p_comp.cpp no matching function for call to `PlayerSteven::PlayerSteven(const char[7])'

note C:\Dev-Cpp\PROJECTS\Player.h:26                 PlayerSteven::PlayerSteven(const PlayerSteven&)

Anyone know how I can get this to compile?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you making your "Custom Players" strong types?  They don't differ at all from the base `Player` class, and you aren't doing anything specific with the types that would require that.  The correct approach would be to instantiate the actual type, `Player steven("Steven")` for example.

Comment: @djechlin: What do you mean? He tried compiling the code in this question.

Comment: @Chad the child classes will be inherently different in the end, I just haven't gotten that far yet :D

Comment: @BenjaminLindley and then saw the compiler errors and threw his hands in the air.

Comment: @Steven, different how?  Differing behavior?  Can you imagine a situation where two players (with different names) have the same behavior?  In that case, I would suggest at least renaming your types to something that is more descriptive about the differences.  `PlayerSteven` doesn't tell a user why that is different than `PlayerBlake` other than by name.  Perhaps something like `AggresivePlayer`, `CautiousPlayer`, `BluffingPlayer`, etc. would be more appropriate?

Comment: @djechlin: No, he didn't throw his hands in the air.  He asked a question about it on Stack Overflow.  He knows that derived classes inherit their parents' functions, he assumed that applied to constructors too.  A perfectly understandable mistake.  The compiler error gives no indication here that the reason it's not working is because it's a constructor.

Comment: @djechlin I tried probably 25 different tweaks to my code to try to get it to work, instead of listing all of the wrong things I did I asked what the right thing to do would be

Comment: @Chad, I'm just having a competition with my friends to see who can program the best AI for a poker player so yes, PlayerTucker will have a different functions to decide how to play based on his cards

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I mostly agree with what you've said, however the error message very clearly does tell you that the issue is with a missing constructor. In fact I can't see how you could interpret it any other way. It isn't much of a logical leap to go from "missing constructor" to "constructor isn't inherited". I do agree however that this might not be obvious to someone inexperienced.

Comment: Well, I fixed my problem and learned something about constructors. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @Steven did you read the compiler error?  what do you think it means?  did you try googling the compiler error and see what came up?  If you tried a lot of tweaks what sorts of things were you trying and which worked or not?  It's also better to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  These are the kinds of things you need to show here when you post a question - even though you got an answer as it stands you have -3 downvotes and it'll probably be closed, which can hurt your ability to ask questions in the future.

Comment: @JBentley: The error message doesn't mention constructors.  It says "no matching function call".

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It says *PlayerSteven::PlayerSteven*, which is obviously a constructor in this context (any beginner C++ book would introduce that concept from an early point). As I've said, I'll agree that a beginner might not deduce the inheritance issue, but the fact that it involves constructors, should be obvious to someone who has spent any time at all writing C++.

Comment: @JBentley: What I said: *"The compiler error gives no indication here that the reason it's not working is because it's a constructor."* -- And it doesn't.  It could give the same message for any undeclared function.  So there is nothing in the error message to indicate that the reason it isn't working this time is peculiar to it being a constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The compiler **does** tell you it's a constructor, because it gives you the function name (which, being the same name as the class, can't be anything *but* a constructor). The only way I can think of contriving an ambiguity is if the code had a namespace `PlayerSteven` with a free function `PlayerSteven` and even then, you'd still know the compiler meant a constructor because it gave you the line number. To insist that the error doesn't indicate a constructor simply because it lacks the word "constructor", is being overly pedantic.

Comment: On another note, I fail to see why this question was closed as not a real question. In what way is it ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical? The question closing system shouldn't be abused simply because you don't like the fact that the question was too simple.

Comment: @JBentley: READ: "The compiler gives no indication here that **THE REASON IT'S NOT WORKING** is because it's a constructor."  Because it gives the exact same error message for functions which *aren't* constructors.  I didn't say the compiler gives no indication that the function is a constructor, and I'm quite sure the OP was never confused about it being a constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I already conceded (twice, once in my original comment), that it may be non-obvious to a beginner WHY the constructor is missing. That doesn't change the fact that you can infer it. In any case this debate is pointless, considering that I was mostly agreeing with your position in the first place.

Comment: I've +1'd this because I think the downvotes and question closing are overly harsh in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ constructors are not inherited. So you have to add them in the subclass:

```
class PlayerSteven: public Player
{
public:
    PlayerSteven()
    {}
    PlayerSteven(string name)
    :Player(name)
    {}
};
```

And the same for the other subclasses  of `Player`.

If you have a recent enough C++11 compiler you can actually inherit constructors, but you have to do it explicitly:

```
class PlayerSteven : public Player
{
public:
    using Player::Player;
};
```

Comment: In C++11, `using Player::Player` should suffice(on compiler that support it, obviously).

Comment: Ok I added the constructors for each subclass but I am getting new errors:  conversion from 'PlayerSteven' to non-scalar type 'PlayerSteven' requested

Comment: @Steven: Yes, unrelated to the previous, and hinted in the deleted answer by @Chad. This is C++, not Java or C#: do not write `PlayerSteven steven = new PlayerSteven("Steven");`, just `PlayerSteven steven("Steven");` or if you need it to be dynamic: `PlayerSteven *steven = new PlayerSteven("Steven");`, but then you'll have to delete it somewhere.

Comment: I changed PlayerSteven steven = new PlayerSteven("Steven") to PlayerSteven steven("Steven"); and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: @Steven because you are trying to instantiate a `PlayerSteven` from a pointer. See my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare and define constructors for the derived types:

```
class PlayerSteven: public Player
{
  PlayerSteven() {}
  PlayerSteven(const std::string& s) : Player(s) {}
};
```

and so on. In C++11 you can use [inherited constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting).

```
class PlayerSteven: public Player
{
  using Player::Player;
};
```

Next, in your main, you are attempting to initialize a `PlayerSteven` object from a pointer to `PlayerSteven`:

```
PlayerSteven steven = new PlayerSteven("Steven");
```

You have no constructor to perform such a conversion, which you probably don't want anyway. You can just instantiat a `PlaverSteven` object:

```
PlayerSteven steven("Steven");
```